# grub does not start my secondary linux entry, both entries start the same linux

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot

I had a previous `Linux Mint 19.2` installed like:

```
/dev/sda3 /boot
/dev/sda4 /
/dev/sda5 /home
```

And then I installed another Linux Mint 20 reusing the `/boot` partition:

```
/dev/sda3 /boot
/dev/sd8 /
```

Now when the grub starts it shows both Linux entries (19.2 and 20) but when I run any of them the one which is started is only the version 20

How do I fix it? I don't even know which other config files I need to post here to begin troubleshooting

#### EDIT

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 223,59 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS240G2G0A-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x578e6a10

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    976895    974848   476M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2       161972222 468875263 306903042 146,4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3          976896   1953458    976563 476,9M 83 Linux
/dev/sda4         1953792 161970175 160016384  76,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       273565696 433581320 160015625  76,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       265566208 273565695   7999488   3,8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       161972224 265564159 103591936  49,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       433582080 468875263  35293184  16,8G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Do you have the option of reinstalling (both) using EFI? Can you post the results of `sudo fdisk -l` (add to your question, please)?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I'm not sure how about the answer, The second linux v20 I can reinstall, but I don't know what exactly to change in the process. The first linux I will avoid touching it. I posted the request output on the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a mess, I'm afraid. Are you sharing the same /home partition as well? Are both systems running Cinnamon?

Comment: both cinnamon, and the /home for second system has no dedicated partition. The used partitions are the mentioned above

Comment: Each boot partition gets one EFI file dedicated to the OS installed in the root system. your version 20 over the previous one hence you have only one of those EFI file required to boot. What you can do is from the Grub menu , press 'e' to edit the view the settings of the Grub  and do a one time change in the settings. check which root the Kernel path of the version 19 entry and change it to point to the correct path and Kernel. then save and exit. and then try to boot the version 19 . If that works, then you can make the edit permanent by editing the same in the /etc/default/Grub  file

Comment: I installed boot-repair on the linux which could start, and followed the comands to purge and reinstall that it gave me. Now both linuxes are running with a shared /boot folder under the /dev/sda3. Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to reinstall both systems. The LM 20 install overwrote the LM 19.2 configs in /boot (which should NOT be shared). Since you're using EFI, you *can* share that (as well as swap):

For LM 19.2

```
/dev/sda1        /boot/efi        # format
/dev/sda4        /                # format
/dev/sda5        /home            # do not format
/dev/sda6        swap
```

For LM 20:

```
/dev/sda1        /boot/efi        # do not format
/dev/sda6        swap
/dev/sda8        /                # format
```

I know this is a lot of work, but it will keep your /boot folders separate and clean.

Comment: Most desktop users do not need the separate /boot folder. Some with Servers or server type installs may want /boot separate. If you share /home you also share configurations. If I do a second Ubuntu install I do not share /home, so I can test user setting changes. But I do create a shared ext4 data partition so all data normally in /home (Documents, Music, etc). The /home without data is small, so I keep it inside / (root).

Comment: I installed boot-repair on the linux which could start, and followed the comands to purge and reinstall that it gave me. Now both linuxes are running with a shared /boot folder under the /dev/sda3. Anyway, thanks for your help